# cd: /Home: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, partitioning, directory, home-directory, cd-command

I saw loads of posts with similar issues; I've looked at the solutions with no luck so far.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop, installed in partition sda5, mounted as `/`. The main part of the disk is allocated to sda6, mounted as `/Home`.

I cannot either:

- cd into this Home directory
- use mkdir to create a sub folder

I can see it and create files etc, when logged in as root, using nautilus, but from a terminal I just get:

```
-su: cd: /Home: No such file or directory
```

I am new to Ubuntu (coming fom Windows) and although I thought I was getting to grips with it, this has me beat.

Any help appreciated. TIA

Comment: Perhaps you should try `cd /home/`. Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: What command exactly do you use to get: `-su: cd: /Home: No such file or directory`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
cd /home
```

Note the lower case `h` - Linux is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks - how dumb am I!! Always looking for a complicated answer to an easy question. Got thrown as I was following a tut and capitals were used for the new directory names and I've just followed suit rather than checking.