# Nemo '/Home' folder freezes

Tags: 13.10, cinnamon, filemanager, nemo

I have Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, and I just installed Cinnamon 2.0 desktop. When I try to open files `/Home` is not responding and freezes.

I can access specific folders like `~/Picture` and `~/Music` from 'search' and 'menu' and it responds, but only the `/Home` folder freezes. I also get a pop up message:

```
Home is not Responding: "Force Quit" or "Wait".
```

[image]

Please Help!!

Comment: Ubuntu is case sensitive, `/home` is lower case. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/444116/cd-home-no-such-file-or-directory http://askubuntu.com/questions/262674/how-do-i-change-the-current-working-directory-to-the-downloads-directory http://askubuntu.com/questions/17062/how-to-open-a-directory-folder-and-a-url-through-terminal ... tons more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove cinnamon
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

The commands above  will remove your current installed version of cinnamon and then reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Actually before the pop up "Home is not responding" the loading wheel appears.  I decided to just let it load and see what happens and before you know it, it loaded. I guess there was two huge file that was installed that took a long time to load. 1 file named "9zkj6qvPTK" has 295,000+ items in it, and the other file named "wtkTPPrTTi" has 730,000+ items in it. It takes a while to load. My question now is What is those files?, Can I delete those file?, and What to do with those files, if I should not delete it? Please help!!